# Second moment of area in parallel axis theorem

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, moment-of-inertia

In parallel axis theorem why Ig second moment of area on axis passing through centre of gravity, is not zero. Even distance between axis and centre of gravity is zero.

Comment: Second moments involve factors of $x^2$ which are strictly non-negative. That integrating such quantities can only give positive values except for the trivial case of a distribution coincident with he axis is a mathematical reality.

Answer (score 1):

If all the mass of a rigid body was squeezed down into a single point (at the center of mass) then the mass moment of inertia would be zero.

But since the mass is distributed in space it would take a finite angular momentum to spin the body up about the center of mass.

The importance of the center of mass is that it is the location when the mass moment of inertia is minimal, but not zero.

In the simplest terms, think of two equal (point) masses separated by a rod. The center of mass is in the middle of the rod, but the mass moment of inertia is the sum of two $m r^2$ terms and it is non-zero. Physically it means it takes torque to rotationaly accelerate the rod and once it starts spinning about the center of mass it carries angular momentum.